# May I withdraw my just-submitted vote to "Reject Tag Edit"?

Tags: discussion, tags

I have just submitted several votes on proposed tag edits to [uae](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/uae) and [taiwan](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/taiwan). I now think my votes to reject were incorrect, and would like to withdraw them.

Is there a process here by which I can withdraw my votes?

Comment: What was the concern on these tag edits? They previously were just blank; there definitely is confusion that Dubai is part of the UAE and that Taiwan is also the ROC. Any progress on getting them approved? Thank you.

Comment: @travelgasm They weren't my proposals, and I didn't see the country inconsistencies. In any event, I thought the proposed definitions were unnecessarily restrictive, but I cannot retrieve the proposed wording and can't be more precise.

Comment: Okay, no worries. They used the same general format as the existing country tags, but perhaps someone can clarify if something else is needed for a summary of the tag.

Comment: Re: *I cannot retrieve the proposed wording*. If you check reviews on your profile page, you can find these links: https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/17667 and https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/17664. I have [mentioned in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/13567/2022/11/23) a SEDE query listing [recent suggested edits on tag-infos](https://data.stackexchange.com/expatriates/query/1231352/recent-suggested-edits-on-tag-infos). (SEDE is only updated once a week - but these suggestions are old enough to be displayed there.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is answered [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394342/is-it-possible-to-retract-an-edit-reject), but to summarize, unfortunately no. However you can still perform some actions on the edit, and even perhaps apply it yourself if it does get rejected.